# Two queries returning different numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why are these queries giving different results

**Query 1**

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) [Year],
DATEPART(Month, Cancel) [Month], COUNT(1) [Count]
FROM Subscription
where DATEPART(YEAR, Cancel) = 2016
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, Cancel),DATEPART(Month, Cancel)
```

This query gives me cancellations for every month in 2016.

**Query 2**

This gives me cancellations for the 9th month in 2016.

```
select count(*) from Subscription
where Cancel >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00.000'
and Cancel <= '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
```

There is a 50k difference in these numbers. `Query 1` is returning 50k more members than `Query 2`

Comment: Well, one is for an entire year and the other is for only one month.

Comment: I'm upvoting the question because I've seen this issue over and over in real life.

Comment: @EricBrandt Me too. I've seen it a few times as well. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you want the second query to be:

```
select count(*) from Subscription
where Cancel >= '2016-09-01' and
      Cancel < '2016-10-01';
```

This will return all cancels in September regardless of whether or not `Cancel` has a time component.

If `Cancel` has a time component, your version will miss cancels on 2016-09-30.

Answer (score 5):

Easy. On the second query you are missing all cancellations from the last day of the month Sept 30, 2016.

You should use: `and Cancel < '2016-10-01 00:00:00.000'`